# why doesn't grunt-karma pass client.args to mocha?

Tags: javascript, testing, gruntjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have a setup with karma. When I run `karma start` everything is ok. Tests are passing. But if try to do the same with grunt-karma  the client.args does't apply!
This is how my karma config block in `Gruntfile.js` looks like:

```
...
karma: {
        watch: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
        },
        CI: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
...
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'karma:watch'
]);
...
```

In my karma.conf.js I have this `client` block with arguments to be passed to mocha:

```
client: {
        mocha: {
            ui: 'tdd'
        }
    },
```

So when I run `grunt dev` mocha doesn't get this `ui` parameter and that's why 
`'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: suite` happens. I know that because if I comment `client` block in karma.conf.js and run `karma start` I get the same error. So why does this happen?

You can see my setup here: https://github.com/dKab/todo/tree/karma